# Query two different postgres databases stored in different servers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgres-fdw

I have two **POSTGRES** databases stored in different servers.

The **"Firstdb"** is **version** **9.2** and it is stored in a  LAN server, port **5432**.

The **"Seconddb"** is **version** **10** and it is stored as localhost to my PC, port **5432**.

I have access to both of them through **pgAdmin4** version **2.0**.

I would like to run query between those two databases to compare data.

Any ideas about how this can be done?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Use a foreign data wrapper

Answer (score 2):

For running federated queries I use most of the time [**postgres_fdw**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/postgres-fdw.html), which creates a foreign table in the source database. Quite handy but has its caveats when dealing with joins.

An example:

```
CREATE SERVER my_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'target.host.com', port '5432', dbname 'targetdb');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER my_server OPTIONS (user 'postgres');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE my_foreign_table (
  id INT,
  desc TEXT
)
SERVER my_server OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'target_table');
```

**EDIT** based on the comments:

Keep in mind that the source database, as any other application, needs access to the target database and it has to be described at the `pg_hba.conf`:

`host yourdb youruser 0.0.0.0 md5`

Another approach is using [**dblink**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib-dblink-function.html), which does not create a foreign table but enables you to fire queries directly to the target database and retrieve the result sets just as if it was local.

Comment: I submited your code successfully. The foreign table created to my "Seconddb". But, if I query select * from foreign_table I get this result:
ERROR:  could not connect to server "my_server"
DETAIL:  FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "postgres", database "nsw", SSL off
SQL state: 08001

Comment: That's a whole other problem you have now. You user has no access to the target database. You have to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file in the target database and add the missing credentials.

Comment: At the `pg_hba.conf` in the target server add something like: `host nsw postgres xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx trust`. Keep in mind that there are other options for `trust`: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: I edited my answer with the last bit regarding the `pg_hba.conf`